# Type 'PayloadType' is not an array type Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am changing my JS files to TS files to learn TS, but I have a problem that I don't know how to fix.

atpPlayerTypes.ts

```
import { ADD_ALL, CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE, TOGGLE_RETIRED } from "../../../redux/actions/atpPlayerAction";

export type PayloadType = {
  id: number;
  first_name: string,
  last_name: string,
  full_name: string,
  retired: boolean,
  birthdate: Date,
  country: object,
  country_id: number,
  create_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
}

export type ToggleRetiredPayloadType = {
  id: number;
  retired: boolean;
  full_name: string,
}

export interface ReturnType {
  type: typeof ADD_ALL | typeof CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE | typeof TOGGLE_RETIRED,
  payload: PayloadType[] | PayloadType | ToggleRetiredPayloadType
};

export type ActionPropsType = {
  type: typeof ADD_ALL | typeof CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE | typeof TOGGLE_RETIRED,
  payload: PayloadType 
};
```

Then, I have my reducer and here I have the problem:

```
import { ADD_ALL, CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE, TOGGLE_RETIRED } from "../actions/atpPlayerAction";
import { PayloadType, ActionPropsType } from '../../types/redux/reducers/atpPlayerType';


const atpPlayerReducer = (state: PayloadType[] = [], action: ActionPropsType): PayloadType[] => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ALL:
     /*
      action.payload is an array of object [{}, {}, ...], so I tried with
      as PayloadType  and I get the error "Type 'PayloadType' is not an array type".  and if I change to PayloadType[] I get the error "(property) payload: PayloadType
Conversion of type 'PayloadType' to type 'PayloadType[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
Type 'PayloadType' is missing the following properties from type 'PayloadType[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more" 

      I also tried in types file use the pipe in Payload like this:

      payload: PayloadType | PayloadType[], but it doesn't work.
    */
      return [...action.payload as PayloadType[]];
    case CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE:
      const exists = state.some(
        (atpPlayer: PayloadType) => atpPlayer.id === action.payload.id 
      );

      if (!exists) {
        return [action.payload as PayloadType, ...state];
      }

      const atpPlayersFiltered = state.map((atpPlayer: PayloadType) => {
        if (atpPlayer.id === action.payload.id) {
          return action.payload;
        }

        return atpPlayer;
      });

      return [...atpPlayersFiltered as PayloadType[]];
    case TOGGLE_RETIRED:
      const atpPlayers = state.filter((atpPlayer: PayloadType) => {
        if (atpPlayer.id === action.payload.id) {
          atpPlayer.retired = action.payload.retired;
        }

        return atpPlayer;
      });

      return [...atpPlayers];
    default: 
      return state;
  }
};

export { atpPlayerReducer };
```

I don't know whick is the reason that I can't use Pipe, when I have another file that I can use pipe. And this file is the following:

```
import {
  PayloadType,
  ReturnType,
  ToggleRetiredPayloadType
} from "../../types/redux/reducers/atpPlayerType";

const ADD_ALL = '[ATP Player] add all';
const CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE = '[ATP Player] create or update one';
const TOGGLE_RETIRED = '[ATP Player] toggle retired';

const addAllATPPlayers = (atpPlayers: PayloadType[]): ReturnType => ({
  type: ADD_ALL,
  payload: atpPlayers,
});

const createOrUpdateATPPlayer = (atpPlayer: PayloadType): ReturnType => ({
  type: CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE,
  payload: atpPlayer,
});

const toggleRetired = (atpPlayer: ToggleRetiredPayloadType): ReturnType => ({
  type: TOGGLE_RETIRED,
  payload: atpPlayer,
});

export {
  addAllATPPlayers,
  createOrUpdateATPPlayer,
  toggleRetired,
  ADD_ALL,
  CREATE_OR_UPDATE_ONE,
  TOGGLE_RETIRED
};
```

if you see, ReturnType has pipes in the payload key and here works.

Comment: Use a discriminated union.

Comment: But I tried how I said and it didn't work.  payload: PayloadType | PayloadType[]